# Simba ODBC: Failed to shut down listener socket client

Tags: google-bigquery

This error message pops up when `Sinn` In button is clicked to authenticate the user.

```
"[Simba][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: Failed to shut down listener socket client."
```

The browser to authenticate the user is not opening, then it will pop up this error message.  How do we make this work?

Comment: Can you determine if you have a "default browser" defined in your Windows environment?  It looks like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-default-browser-in-windows-020c58c6-7d77-797a-b74e-8f07946c5db6) is the recipe.  What is the browser on your Windows machine?  It would appear that some other users encountered this message/error when they had no default browser defined.

Comment: Yes, I have.  I also gave some more details in the Google Community.